# Model Validations are not working on data table pages except the 1st one

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am submitting the form using ajax call in MVC .net I have model validation which is that only numeric number should be entered in the input filed this validation is working on the 1st page but not on the other pages of Data-Table. I think this problem is due to DOM binding. Can someone please help me?

```
$('#bulkupdate').on('click', function (e) {
                debugger;
                // Prevent actual form submission
                e.preventDefault();
                var data = table.$('input').serializeArray();
                // Submit form data via Ajax
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("BulkUpdate", "Home")',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#myModalContent').html(data);
                        $('#myModal').modal('show');
                    }
                });
                });
```

and my data table code is

```
<form id="share">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="container col-md-12">
        <table id="myTable" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered dataTable">

            <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.tags.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.tags[i].Id)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.tags[i].Id)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.tags[i].TagName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.tags[i].TagCategory)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                            {
                                @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.tags[i].TagValue, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "TagVaule_" + Model.tags[i].Id, @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.tags[i].TagValue, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.tags[i].TagValue, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "TagVaule_" + Model.tags[i].Id, @class = "form-control",@readonly = "readonly"} })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.tags[i].TagValue, "", new { @class = "text-danger"})
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
            </div>
        </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="bulkupdate">BulkUpdate</button>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `is working on the 1st page but not on the other pages of Data-Table` I dont quite get what you mean. You mean you are paging table ?

Comment: yes I am paging the table

Comment: Do you generate all items in DOM at the same time? Or just the number of items on one page?

Comment: I don't know but if i load all items in DOM then the problem will be solved.But i don't know how i can load all items in DOM.

Comment: In my opinion, You don't need to load and check all items, Just load & check to validate the number of available items on each page.